# Herarchy query using sequelize / nodejs

Tags: node.js, recursion, promise, sequelize.js

I am trying to load a hierarchy in my database. I have a column with parentId in my table so every row can have a parent. But I am having problems using recursion and promises.

```
function read (options) {
  return serviceItemAttributeModel.findOne({
    id: options.id,
    id_organization: options.idOrganization
  })
  .then((attribute) => {
    if (attribute) {
      return loadChildren(attribute, attribute);
    } else {
      return attribute;
    }
  });
}

function loadChildren (root, attribute) {
  return serviceItemAttributeModel.findAll({
    where: {
      id_parent: attribute.id
    }
  })
  .then((attributes) => {
    if (!attributes) {
      return root;
    } else {
      attribute.serviceItemAttributes = [];
      attributes.forEach(function (each) {
        attribute.serviceItemAttributes.push(each);
        return loadChildren(root, each);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

So, I call ***read*** that calls ***loadChildren*** to recursively try to load all entities (by looking children of an entity) and I get an undefined value. Any ideas?

I am also getting an error on console: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it.

**EDIT:**

*Came up if this solution after Nosyara help. thanks!:*

```
function read (options) {
  return serviceItemAttributeModel.findOne({
    where: {
      id: options.attributeId,
      id_organization: options.idOrganization
    }
  })
  .then((attribute) => {
    if (!attribute) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(attribute);
      });
    } else {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        attribute.queryCount = 1;
        resolve(attribute);
      })
      .then((attribute) => loadChildren(attribute, attribute));
    }
  });
}

function loadChildren (root, attribute) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    return serviceItemAttributeModel.findAll({
      where: {
        id_parent: attribute.id
      }
    })
    .then((attributes) => {
      attributes.length = attributes.length || 0;
      root.queryCount = root.queryCount - 1 + attributes.length;
      if (root.queryCount === 0) {
        resolve(root);
      } else if (root.queryCount > 10) {
        let error = new Error('Service attribute hierarchy cant have more then 10 levels');
        error.statusCode = 500;
        reject(error);
      } else {
        attribute.serviceItemAttributes = [];
        attributes.forEach(function (each) {
          attribute.serviceItemAttributes.push(each);
          return loadChildren(root, each).then(() => {
            resolve(root);
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messing up with async calls and returns. You can convert both function to async, and pass through result structure to be updated. Example:

```
function read(...) {
  return new Promise(function (accept, reject) {
    // You code goes here, but instead of return
    accept(resultFromAsyncFunction);
  }); 
}
// ...
read(...).then(function(resultData) { ... });
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5nn198fc/1/) is example of Promise recursion.